# Why is ones_like listed as a ufunc?

Tags: numpy, numpy-ufunc

I was surprised to see `numpy.ones_like` listed in the list of ufuncs [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/ufuncs.html). Is this just an oversight, or is there specific use case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is an oversight in the documentation.  `ones_like` is not a `ufunc`. It is implemented in [numpy/core/numeric.py](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/numeric.py), along with `zeros_like` and similar functions.  It uses the shape and data type of the argument, but it does not perform an elementwise operation.